# Wordpress WP_User_Query + Relevanssi

Tags: wordpress, search

I have a search bar on a site which runs a `WP_User_Query` and lists users.

It'd be great to tap into the power of *Relevanssi* so more info on a user can be searched e.g. custom fields etc.

Relevannsi has a `relevanssi_do_query($your_query_object);` ([link](https://www.relevanssi.com/knowledge-base/relevanssi_do_query/)) function which works great with `WP_Query`... however does nothing to `WP_User_Query`.

Has anyone found a way to solve this?

I'm aware of the *Index and search user profiles* setting in the backend, however this affects all instances of search results, which isn't what I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the latest version of the plugin solves the issue.